# Accessing googlecl using python script

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python gtk program which uses googlecl tools like listing google calendar appointments, accessing the google blog etc. However I do not know how to call the command in python gtk.

The command for running googlecl in the terminal is
   **google calendar list --date 2010-12-02**

This command would list all the appointments in google calendar on the 2nd of december if entered in the terminal. However I do not know how to make python gtk do the same thing. Any help would be appreciated.

*Googlecl is a command line tool released by google to facilate easy management of common tasks like google calendar, google blogger, google docs etc. You can find more info on **code.google.com/p/googlecl/***

Comment: Since your question is python development related, http://stackoverflow.com/ is probably a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very good chance (If you're using Python 3) that you'll want to use the [[image: Python] Subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) which will allow you to make, and collect output from, system calls - like the `googlecl` command.

If you're using Python < 2.6 (Odds are you aren't since 2.6 is the official version in the repos) Then you'll want to use the [[image: Python] Commands Module](https://docs.python.org/library/commands.html). This is depreciated for the above Subprocess Module and is removed in Python 3.

Comment: googlecl is actually written in Python. I have written some scripts that use Subprocess for it, but maybe someone somewhere has done the clever thing, and is importing it and using it directly...

Comment: I will be using python 1.6 since that is the default version which comes with ubuntu and will ensure compatibility for all the users. So I basically run the following python command to get the output,

  
  import subprocess

    
  output = subprocess.Popen("google calendar list --date 2010-12-02")